# Panel data on US presidents electoral legitimacy

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, public-opinion, data-sources

[This Gallup poll from November 2016](http://www.gallup.com/poll/197441/accept-trump-legitimate-president.aspx) asked the question:

> " Now that Donald Trump has been declared the winner and will be inaugurated in January, will you accept him as the legitimate president, or not?"

[On the same page](http://www.gallup.com/poll/197441/accept-trump-legitimate-president.aspx), Gallup reports of asking the same question following G.W. Bush's election.

**My question:** Do you know of any dataset containing answers to a similar question, but for more than two elections?

In the best of worlds, I would be looking for a panel dataset where the *same* people are asked the question across several elections.

Comment: Both the 2000 and 2016 elections were heavily disputed because the winner received fewer total votes than one of the losers, which made some people question the legitimacy/fairness of the electoral system. It's unlikely Gallup would ask such a question when the electoral winner was also the majority winner. That being said, I'm somewhat surprised they didn't ask for the 2004 election, which was similarly (though less strongly) contested.

Comment: I was hoping maybe the 2000 election sparked an interest for the question, and that the question would have been ask in all subsequent elections, for comparison sake. I have found extensive data on the 2000 election from CBS polls, available at ICPSR: goo.gl/yn5mMZ. There is also a poll there for 2004 showing that, maybe unsurprisingly, more people supported the legitimacy of GWB's election in 2004. Unfortunately, nothing for earlier or later elections other than 2016 (although there seems to have been some ---- admittedly milder --- debates about legitimacy in other races too goo.gl/LM8b5E).

Comment: I think the question is just a roundabout way of asking people if they believe the electoral college should remain. Perhaps searching for poll data that explicitly asks that might return some useful results.

Comment: Related: [Are there other US presidential elections in which the majority of supporters of the losing side said the election was stolen from them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60452/)